# Security exceptionHandling cant register successfully,Filter has somthing wrong

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
<spring-boot.version>3.1.3</spring-boot.version>

-------SecConfig---------

@Autowired
private AnonymousAuthenticationHandler anonymousAuthenticationHandler;
@Bean
public JwtTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new JwtTokenFilter();
}
...
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   ...
http.exceptionHandling((exception) -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(anonymousAuthenticationHandler))
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/web/authenticate").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
   .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   ...

-------AnonymousAuthenticationHandler ---------
@Component
public class AnonymousAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ResponseUtil.out(Result.error().code(ResultCode.NO_AUTH).message("匿名用户无权限访问！"));
    }
}
}
```

When I initiate a request, the request is successfully entered **authenticationJwtTokenFilter**, but when the request not auth, it cant into my **anonymousAuthenticationHandler**, when I check the type of chainFilter, discover its type seems a bit problematic. For example, its type is **ApplicationFinterConfig** instead of **FilterChainProxy** and my filterChains just own seven filter

## My project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyimU.png)

## Other project[click here for check the code](https://github.com/markvivv/springboot-security-jwt-example)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUp0Q.png)

My configuration is not much different from his configuration
What is the cause of this problem and how can I modify my code

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
//获取登录请求地址
@Value("${request.login.url}")
private String loginUrl;

//获取登录请求地址
@Value("${request.logout.url}")
private String logoutUrl;

@Value("${jwt.expire}")
private int expire;

@Autowired
private LoginFailureHandler loginFailureHandler;

@Autowired
private SecurityUserDetailsService securityUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private RedisUtil redisUtil;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // 如果是登录或者登出接口，直接放行
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        if (requestURI.equals(loginUrl) || requestURI.equals(logoutUrl)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        // 从request获取token
        validToken(request);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        loginFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);
        logger.error("Cannot set user authentication!", e);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private void validToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException, ValidateException {
    //从头部获取token信息
    String token = request.getHeader("X-token");
    //如果请求头部没有获取到token，则从请求的参数中进行获取
    if (ObjUtil.isEmpty(token)) {
        token = request.getParameter("X-token");
    }
    //如果请求参数中也不存在token信息，则抛出异常
    if (ObjUtil.isEmpty(token)) {
        throw new CustomAuthException("token不存在");
    }
    //判断redis中是否存在该token
    String tokenKey = "";
    String redisToken = (String) RedisUtil.string.builder().build().get(tokenKey);

    //如果redis里面没有token,说明该token失效
    if (ObjUtil.isEmpty(redisToken)) {
        throw new CustomAuthException("token已过期");
    }
    // 如果token和Redis中的token不一致，则验证失败
    if (!token.equals(redisToken)) {
        throw new CustomAuthException("token与记录不一致");
    }
    //如果存在token，则从token中解析出用户名
    JWT jwt = new JWT();
    try {
        JWTUtil.verify(token, "signer".getBytes());
        JWTValidator.of(token).validateDate(DateUtil.date());
        jwt = JWTUtil.parseToken(token);
    } catch (ValidateException e) {
        throw new CustomAuthException("token已过期");
    }
    
    //获取用户信息
    UserDetails user = JSONUtil.toBean(jwt.getPayload("user").toString(), User.class);
    //获取权限列表
    user = securityUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());

    //如果用户为空，则解析失败
    if (ObjUtil.isEmpty(user)) {
        throw new CustomAuthException("token中不存在用户信息");
    }
    //此处需要获取token过期时间，如果过期时间剩下预设时间的1/4，则为用户续期token，时间为预设的1/2
    long expired = redisUtil.getExpired(tokenKey);
    if (expired < expire / 4) {
        redisUtil.expire(tokenKey, expire / 2);
    }

    //创建身份验证对象
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null,
            user.getAuthorities());
    authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
    //设置到Spring Security上下文
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
}
```

}

```
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //设置客户端响应编码格式
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    //获取输出流
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    //提示信息
    String message = null;
    //判断异常类型
    if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
        message = "账户过期,登录失败！";
    } else if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        message = "用户名或密码错误,登录失败！";
    } else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
        message = "密码过期,登录失败！";
    } else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
        message = "账户被禁用,登录失败！ ";
    } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
        message = "账户被锁,登录失败！";
    } else if (exception instanceof InternalAuthenticationServiceException) {
        message = "账户不存在,登录失败！ ";
    } else if (exception instanceof CustomAuthException) {
        message = exception.getMessage();
    } else {
        message = "登录失败！";
    }
    //将错误信息转换成JSON

    ResponseUtil.out(Result.error().code(ResultCode.ERROR).message(message));
}
```

this is my **JwtTokenFilter**, In addition, I also provided the **LoginFailureHandler** for you. The **CustomAuthException** is extends AuthenticationException. Are you aware of any potential problems in my code? @DingHao. thanks

Comment: `authenticationJwtTokenFilter` this is not from the spring security documentation, why are you using JWTs as sessions, why have you written custom security and not read the spring documentation on how to actually build security?

Comment: please post your JwtTokenFilter  code

Comment: @Toerktumlare Your question is excellent. I'm doing this project to get a better grasp of Spring Security, and I'll check the official documentation for your hints

Comment: If you are learning, dont read poor blogposts.

Comment: I just graduated from university and work a year, there are many need me to further study and master, once again, thank you for your teaching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, it's so crazy bug .and I've fixed it perfectly

I tried a lot, When I copy the reference project to my project ,it run successfully, then I found that my SecConfig path is: **/config/security/SecConfig.java**, the other I copied to my project is **/config/security/config/SecurityConfig.java**.

After continuous attempts to compare and query information, I found that the configuration file takes effect only in ralative path **/config**

My problem has been solved perfectly. thanks for all!